# How to make 3 things stay on the same line with the middle thing centered?

Tags: html, css

I made three things on the same line with divs and CSS float left and right. But the thing in the middle is not centered and it's not wide enough. How do I make the middle thing centered?
Edit: Thankyou all for helping me. I appreciated

```css
.box1 {
  float: left;
}

.box2 {
  float: left;
}

.box3 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
<div class="box2">
  <table>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="box3">
  <p>Hello again</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to use float? That is, is there a requirement for text for example to wrap around the left and right divs, or is it always the case that you basically want 3 columns, albeit with the center one centered on the parent element and not evenly spaced from the other two elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` attribute for `design` items side by side. And for `table` you can use tr td th elements . Additionally you i used `justify-content:start-center-end` attributes Finally You should give `width:auto` value to the `box` classes

```css
.box1 {
display:flex;
justify-content:start;
width:auto;
}

.box2 {
width:auto;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
}

.box3 {
 width:auto;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:end;
}

table, th, td {
 border:1px solid black;
}

.container {
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box1">

  <p>hello</p>

</div>

<div class="box2">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="box3">

  <p>Hello again</p>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` in a div container.

Maybe this can help you:

```css
.container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.box2 {
    background-color: green;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="box1">

      <p>hello</p>

    </div>

    <div class="box2">

      <table>

      </table>

    </div>

    <div class="box3">

      <p>Hello again</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't center the central element, it puts equal space between it and the left and right elements.